# can i use wildcards in msbuld property methods

Tags: methods, properties, msbuild

I am using the string.Replace msbuild method to modify strings in the property, can I use wildcards ( . ?  *) and/or other regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

No, not with String.Replace, cause .NET method doesn't allow you to use any wildcards.
But same way you are calling String.Replace() - you can call Regex.Replace, which opens you full power of .NET regex engine, not only wildcards ;).